# Install4J: Only download changed components

Tags: install4j

My Install4j project consists of several components, which are downloaded from a server.

Can I get Install4j to only download the changed components when running an update? At the moment the installer downloads all components even if they haven't changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such detection in install4j because there is no concept of a version of an installation component. You would have to implement the component versioning yourself, then you could selectively switch off the installation components before the "Install files" action runs, by calling

```
context.getInstallationComponentById("123").setSelected(false);
```

For each installation component, replacing "123" by the actual ID.